# Why C++ standard library does not pass predicates as &&

Tags: c++, stl, function-object

In C++ stl, there is e.g.:

```
template<class InputIt, class UnaryPredicate>
constexpr InputIt find_if( InputIt first, InputIt last, UnaryPredicate p );
```

My question is: why there is not:

```
... find_if(..., UnaryPredicate &&p);
```

In my understanding it would be more "universal". R-value predicates still would be passed by value. Additionally, L-value predicates could be passed too:

```
struct MyComplexPred { 
  MyComplexPred(MyComplexPred const &) = delete; // expensive/"impossible" copy
  MyComplexPred() { /*...*/ }
  bool operator()(int val) const { return true; /*...*/ }
};
int fun() {
  MyComplexPred pred;
  std::vector<int> a, b;
  std::find_if(a.begin(), a.end(), pred);  // impossible, no copy
  std::find_if(b.begin(), b.end(), pred);  // impossible, reuse predicate
  ...
```

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51187685/c-passing-function-objects-as-lvalues-and-or-rvalues) but I wonder why the suggested &&-passing with reference collapsing is not used in stl for predicates and other function objects.

Comment: My guess, the standard allows the predicate to be copied by the algorithm.  Having the pass by value is an easy way to enforce that the predicate is copyable.

Comment: Seems related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48803927/why-does-stdfind-iffirst-last-p-not-take-predicate-by-reference

Comment: In the linked question I found this answer: "Pass by reference (T&) doesn't work for temporary or const objects, T const& doesn't work for non-const&, i.e., the only choice would be T&& (forwarding reference) which didn't exist pre-C++11 and the algorithm interfaces didn't change since they were introduced with C++98." so I believe it is still true.